# Salesforce conditionally display fields based on value?

Tags: formula-field, fields, conditional

Is there a way to conditionally display a field based on its value in a Page layout only using Formula and not with VF Page or additional Page Layout.

Eg: A formula field checkbox should select the value 'Yes' if a contact's
    birth date falls in the current month otherwise the field itself should not
    display.

Currently I am able to display the field as selected if the above criteria is met, otherwise its showing unchecked. Can I remove the field itself if the criteria is not met using some simple Formula or other method other than VF or other complex way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea submitted for this.. 
Please vote..

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BroxAAC

Answer (score 1):

I think yes you can do that. You can create two Record types with two different page layouts. In one page layout remove the fields.

Now based on the checkbox value you can change the `recordType` and it will also change the layout.

So to achieve this you need 2 Recordstypes, 2 page Layouts and one WF field update.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I was looking for something straight  without any additional PageLayout or VF page.

Comment: @RobertThomas yes its a bit complex.

Comment: I can see an Idea submitted for this and which is in Development Stage. Suprisingly it submitted 10 years back and still in development stage..  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BroxAAC

Comment: @RobertThomas actually Salesforce seems to be moving quite quickly with that one!